# roslaunch and map_server

Tags: navigation, mapping, roslaunch, yaml, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone know how to do the following using roslaunch?

> rosrun map_server map_server mymap.yaml

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9379/roslaunch-and-map_server/) by [jdt141](https://answers.ros.org/users/247/jdt141/) on ROS Answers with karma: 118 on 2011-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

you can try the following:

```
<launch>

  <arg name="map_file" default="$(find [package where your yaml file is])/mymap.yaml"/>

  <!-- Run the map server -->
  <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(arg map_file)" />

</launch>
```

I would strongly advise you to have a look at [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup) tutorial that explains how to setup the navigation stack for a robot.

Also have a look at the xml tags allowed in launch files [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML).

Raph

---

Originally posted by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) with karma: 1382 on 2011-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5